# cookies keep resetting with eel python

Tags: javascript, python, cookies, electron, eel

my app made using python's eel library expects to retrieve data from cookies, the data is not critical and only contains a string of the last path the user worked with, so storing that in a database isn't ideal. However, cookies keeps resetting whenever the app starts.

I tried retrieving and storing the cookies like you normally would with js
I use cookie.js from https://github.com/florian/cookie.js/

```js
// store
function rememberLastPath(path){
    cookie.set('lastPath', path);
}

// retrieve
function getLastPath(){
   cookie.get('lastPath');
}
```

this works but when the app is restarted cookies are reset.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, the snippet does not provide too much context other than you are trying to set and get a cookie called `lastPath` to store the last workspace path.

Some of the most common root causes for cookie persistence errors are:

- Is an expiration date being set when calling `cookie.set()`? - An explicit expiration may be needed.

```js
function rememberLastPath(path) {
  cookie.set('lastPath', path, 
  {
    expires: 30 // expires in 30 days
  });
}
```

- Does `cookie.set()` return any errors, warnings or response that could provide clues?. If so, please share them.

```js
function setCookie(key, value) {
  try {
    cookie.set(key, value);
  } catch (error) {
    console.error('Error setting cookie', error);
    throw error;
  }
}
```

- What browser are you using?. Some browsers like chrome require cookies to be set via HTTP only.
- Is the domain being passed to `cookie.set()` correctly?.

```js
const domain = '.example.com';
cookie.set(key, value, {
  domain
});
```

- Can you see the cookie in the browser dev tools?. If so, please share the information you can see there.